# How was this directed graph made?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was just confused on how the professor was able to draw these three directed graphs. If someone could explain that it would be appreciated.

[How was this directed graph made?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xv1b.png)

Comment: If you have a relation $R$ over a set $A$, then you have a directed graph with vertices the elements of $A$ and a directed edge $a\to b$, for $a,b\in A$, whenever $aRb$. For example, there is an arrow from $(5)$ to $(2)$, because $3|5+2\cdot 2=9$, which tells us that $5R2$. Their $5$ looks a lot like a $9$. By the way, the diagram is intended to be a single graph. It just happens that it is disconnected.

Comment: ... and there are everywhere "self-arrows" ; for example the self-arrow on 1 is explained by the fact that $1$ is at the same time an "a" and a "b" because $1+2 \times 1=3$ divisible by $3$.